# How to get rid of the shadow between AppBarLayout and TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout for a fragment with three tabs. The XML code of the layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".fragment.PatternAssignmentFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

There is a shadow showing between the AppBarLayout and TabLayout, as can be seen in the image (shadow above the red line):

[image]

I have tried various tweaks in the xml to remove it, but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: set app:elevation="0dp" inside AppBarLayout, then clean and rebuild project. I use it for my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `app:elevation="0dp"` instead of `android:elevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Use **`app:elevation="0dp"`** in your `AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

or Use **`getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`** in your actvity

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately this did not work, though it seems like it should work

Comment: @Nora have you tried `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`

Comment: Ah no! I saw that now, will try :) hopefully it works!

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, using getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0) did not work either. Maybe this is because I am working in a fragment and not an activity, so I had to use: 

ActionBar mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setElevation(0);

Comment: @Nora agree with you please post that as an answer so it can help the other user

Answer (score 1):

If android:elevation didn't work then try app:elevation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Try with CoordinatorLayout instead of Constraintlayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".fragment.PatternAssignmentFragment">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Unfortunately none of the two suggestions worked

Comment: My answer didn't help you ?

Comment: sorry no, I tried both app:elevation and android:elevation with no results

Comment: Let me try it by myself then let see where is the problme

Comment: @Nora try with coordinator layout.

Answer (score 1):

Open **app_bar_main.xml** and set `app:elevation="0dp"` inside `AppBarLayout`, then clean and rebuild project.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

...
        app:elevation="0dp">

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```