# How to remove shadow line effect on transparent toolbar.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

[Almost worked]
[How to get rid of the shadow between AppBarLayout and TabLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556516/how-to-get-rid-of-the-shadow-between-appbarlayout-and-tablayout)

[SOLVED]

added background tint to transparent !!

I have selected navigation bar page after creating a project how can i make my toolbar transparent ?.

I have tried many stackoverflow answers none of them worked. There is always a shadow line below the toolbar.
how can i get rid of this ?

[image]

After trying suggested page . Still there is a color difference .. tried

android:background="@android:color/transparent" didn't worked

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. It did set the elevation problem but there is still a color difference

Comment: Please do not add things like '[EDITED]' and '[SOLVED]' to your question titles.